# how to use django rest filtering with mongoengine for list filtering

Tags: django-views, django-rest-framework, mongoengine, django-filter, restframeworkmongoengine

**views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from rest_framework_mongoengine.viewsets import ModelViewSet as MongoModelViewSet

from app.serializers import *

from rest_framework_mongoengine.generics import * 

from rest_framework import filters    


def index_view(request):
    context = {}
    return TemplateResponse(request, 'index.html', context)


class ToolViewSet(MongoModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ToolSerializer
    my_filter_fields = ('crop', 'district','taluka','circle','year',) 

    def get_kwargs_for_filtering(self):
        filtering_kwargs = {} 

        for field in  self.my_filter_fields: # iterate over the filter fields
            field_value = self.request.query_params.get(field) # get the value of a field from request query parameter
            if field_value: 
                filtering_kwargs[field] = field_value
        return filtering_kwargs 

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Tool.objects.all() 
        filtering_kwargs = self.get_kwargs_for_filtering() # get the fields with values for filtering 
        if filtering_kwargs:
            queryset = Tool.objects.filter(**filtering_kwargs) # filter the queryset based on 'filtering_kwargs'
        return queryset
```

This is my code.

it's work for filtering exactly what we want to serach.

for example : http://api/tool/?district=Nasik&crop=banana

But, it's not working for list fileds
for example :  http://api/tool/?district=Nasik&district=Pune
this gives output: [] (empty)

How to get this filter working to get all district "Nasik" OR district "Pune"

Can you please help me what I have to changes in my code for get data if I search http://api/tool/?crops=guava,banana 
Or http:../tool/?district=Nasik,Pune
gives me correct output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend taking a look at [django-rest-framework-filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters). You can then use stuff like `__in` in your query params...

But if you want to proceed with your approach, I would add the logic in your `get_kwargs_for_filtering` method somehow like this:

```
def get_kwargs_for_filtering(self):
    filtering_kwargs = {} 

    for field in  self.my_filter_fields: # iterate over the filter fields
        field_value = self.request.query_params.get(field) # get the value of a field from request query parameter
        if field_value: 
            if ',' in field_value: # put your queryParams into an array and use the built-in django filter method '__in'
                filtering_kwargs[field + '__in'] = field_value.split(',')
            else:
                filtering_kwargs[field] = field_value
    return filtering_kwargs
```

With this, a call to http://api/tool/?crops=guava,banana should produce the desired behavior.
I can't test if it works now, but this should lead you to the right direction.

Comment: ,do you means In my fields = {'name': ['exact', 'in', 'startswith']} I have to use this ?

Comment: Can you please gives me some hint, it will helps

Comment: you are awesome... thanks a lot, that's exactly what I want...!!! after searching 1000 question get the correct answer.

Comment: Excellent logic

Comment: btw, django-filter has builtin support for `__in` queries as of the 0.13 release. It's no longer necessary to use drf-filters for just that feature.

Comment: @Remi , suppose we have data (crop,district,year..etc) in  properties fields, then our code is consider  field is properties, and our properties field is dictionary .then  how can we run this code for  dict field(crop,guava)    properties  : { "crop" : "guava" , "district" : nasik" }  ,can you please help me for this dict field ?

Comment: @Remi, can you please check my another question, here .   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479932/using-geojson-data-format-how-can-we-write-dynamic-query-for-porpoerites-dictio

Comment: @Sherpa , thanks django-filters work in HTML file too?, I mean in my index.HTML file I have two boxes "crop" and "district" . if someone fill this and click on submit Button, like : "crop= guava" and "district : pune" . then quey like http://api/?crop= guava&?district = pune . then this query automatic work? What I have to change in my code for call input parameter then display that data?

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is somewhat old. This is a question that is still important and valid in later versions of Django, DRF and MongoEngine.

At the time of this answer I am running

```
Django==4.1.3
djangorestframework==3.14
django-rest-framework-mongoengine==3.4.1
mongoengine==0.24.2
django-filter==22.1
# patched version of django-mongoengine-filter to support Django 4.0
# https://github.com/oussjarrousse/django-mongoengine-filter 
# Pull request https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-mongoengine-filter/pull/16 
django-mongoengine-filter>=0.3.5
```

The idea in this answer is to add filtering support to `django-rest-framework-mongoengine` using `django-mongoengine-filter` that is an replacement or an extension to `django-filter` and should work the same way as `django-filter`.

First let's edit the project/settings.py file. Find the INSTALLED_APPS variable and make sure the following "Django apps" are added:

```
# in settings.py:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...,
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_mongoengine",
    "django_filters",
    # ...,
]
```

the app django_filters is required to add classes related to filtering infrastructure, and other things including html templates for DRF.

Then in the variable `REST_FRAMEWORK` we need to edit the values associated with the key: `DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS`

```
# in settings.py:

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # ...
    "DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS": [
        "filters.DjangoMongoEngineFilterBackend",
        # ...
    ],
    # ...
}
```

`DjangoMongoEngineFilterBackend` is a custom built filter backend that we need to add to the folder (depending on how you structure your project) in the file `filters`

```
# in filters.py:
from django_filters.rest_framework.backends import DjangoFilterBackend

class DjangoMongoEngineFilterBackend(DjangoFilterBackend):
    # filterset_base = django_mongoengine_filter.FilterSet
    """
    Patching the DjangoFilterBackend to allow for MongoEngine support
    """

    def get_filterset_class(self, view, queryset=None):
        """
        Return the `FilterSet` class used to filter the queryset.
        """
        filterset_class = getattr(view, "filterset_class", None)
        filterset_fields = getattr(view, "filterset_fields", None)

        if filterset_class:
            filterset_model = filterset_class._meta.model

            # FilterSets do not need to specify a Meta class
            if filterset_model and queryset is not None:
                element = queryset.first()
                if element:
                    queryset_model = element.__class__
                    assert issubclass(
                        queryset_model, filterset_model
                    ), "FilterSet model %s does not match queryset model %s" % (
                        filterset_model,
                        str(queryset_model),
                    )

            return filterset_class

        if filterset_fields and queryset is not None:
            MetaBase = getattr(self.filterset_base, "Meta", object)

            element = queryset.first()
            if element:
                queryset_model = element.__class__
                class AutoFilterSet(self.filterset_base):
                    class Meta(MetaBase):
                        model = queryset_model
                        fields = filterset_fields

            return AutoFilterSet

        return None
```

This custom filter backend will not raise the exceptions that the original django-filter filter backend would raise. The django-filter DjangoFilterBackend access the key `model` in `QuerySet` as in `queryset.model`, however that key does not exist in MongoEngine.

Maybe making it available in MongoEngine should be considered:
https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2707
https://github.com/umutbozkurt/django-rest-framework-mongoengine/issues/294

Now we can add a custom filter to the ViewSet:

```
# in views.py
from rest_framework_mongoengine.viewsets import ModelViewSet

class MyModelViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    filter_fields = ["a_string_field", "a_boolean_field"]
    filterset_class = MyModelFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        return queryset
```

Finally let's get back to `filters.py` and add the `MyModelFilter`

```
# in filters.py
from django_mongoengine_filter import FilterSet, StringField, BooleanField
class MyModelFilter(FilterSet):
    """
    MyModelFilter is a FilterSet that is designed to work with the django-filter.
    However the original django-mongoengine-filter is outdated and is causing some troubles
    with Django>=4.0.
    """

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [
            "a_string_field",
            "a_boolean_field",
        ]

    a_string_field = StringFilter()
    a_boolean_field = BooleanFilter()
```

That should do the trick.